# Are locks as easy to pick as in the movies?

Tags: security

Are door locks as easy to pick as in the movies? They seem to only take around 2-3 seconds to pick be it with a credit card or a hairpin. Is this realistic? Or is it simply Hollywood being Hollywood?

How long would it take an expert to open a random door lock of a house or that of a hotel room?

Comment: I've picked simple grill/bathroom locks with things like scissors and pins with no training. Even orangutans have done it: http://www.time.com/time/magazine/article/0,9171,30198,00.html But picking a medium security standard door lock or padlock is much harder.

Comment: Does anyone notable claim locks are as easy to pick as shown in the movies?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrink it has been the policy of the site to allow for challenging claims shown in the movies that infer stuff like this.  I dislike it but that is the policy.

Comment: Actually the difficulty in picking the locks in a movie is proportional to how close the hero is to being caught.  Typically a lock will take X-1 seconds to pick with X being the number of seconds between when the hero starts trying to pick the lock and when they will be caught.

Comment: If you want some practical advice google up the MIT guide to lock picking. The basic technique is fiddly and requires a degree of touch to do quickly or well---more than I ever developed---but with enough time and patience I have opened a name-brand padlock without the key using jury-rigged picks. A cousin was able to do it in a minute or two on a number of sample locks.

Comment: My jaw dropped at the speed a locksmith opened my apartment door using the little gun-shaped gizmo you see in the movies sometimes. The only thing that wasn't 100% as fast as the movies is that he sprayed the lock with WD-40 first; other than that, "snap-snap...There you go..."

Comment: Questioning the realism of things in movies is sometimes on-topic: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/random-claims-from-fantasy-stories-and-movies

Comment: A bump key or gun can do it in seconds. I taught each of my kids at age 5 or 6 to pick locks, and a normal house lock can take them a minute or two. It is extraordinarily easy for basic locks, but the difficulty scales up rapidly!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This question is way too generic, because there is a variety of locks and they can differ quite a lot in what principle they're based on. However one thing *can* be said: most depictions of lock picking in movies and TV are inaccurate to say the least. They look more like the actors are handling a padlock (from the way they move the tools :)) than one in a door.

You should perhaps check out the Wikipedia entry on [locksport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locksport) to form your own opinion. Especially skim or read through "The MIT Guide to Lock Picking" linked from the Wikipedia article. This will give you a basic understanding for at least one lock type which is in widespread use.

Skilled people are indeed able to *pick* many a lock in under a minute, but most certainly not in 2-3 seconds. And keep in mind that lockpicking refers to non-destructive opening of a lock.

As for hotel room doors the situation is slightly different, because in some cases the access cards are prone to special attacks. So for them it is more likely. And some of the technology shown in spy movies has actually seen real successors. But that's a completely different league from mechanical locks. Which was also the reason for my initial remark of this being a (too) broad question.

Comment: and hotel locks generally accept a master key, which can make the lock less secure (it accepts 2 distinct keys not just one)

Comment: Some electronic hotel locks had a vulnerability: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/08/24/hotel_keylock_hack/

Answer (score 8):

Common door locks can be opened in 2-3 seconds with a bump key.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_bumping
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hr23tpWX8lM

Comment: If a single tap does it as shown in the video, you're quite lucky. Usually you will take longer than 2-3 seconds *and* a series of taps, even with bump keys. Oh, and expensive locks - unlike shown in the video - are usually built with higher precision and thus *more* prone to lock bumping than cheap ones.

Comment: An O-ring lets you do a series of taps in 2-3 seconds. 

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=WpH_t0u5Ybg#t=543s
Locks with bump-proof cylinders are more expensive.

Comment: cool. Hadn't seen that as of yet.  And what I meant before that some more expensive than normal cylinders are still not bump proof and are actually more prone to bump keys because of the extra precision.

Comment: Really, it takes one bump to open the lock.  However, it can take you many tries to get it just right.  but there's no reason why you couldn't do it in under a second if you got lucky.